# PHP - Storing a session in a query every time user loads query

Tags: php, session

I'm a rookie PHP coder.

I would like to store a session every time the user runs this query so that the ID gets stored, so that ID is not in the next query.

I'll explain what my website does: I have a button that refreshes the page and provides a message to the user. Every time they refresh the page it's a "random" message, I want it so that messages are not repeated.

Here's my code:

```
<?php 

session_start();
include 'include/mysql_connect.php';

$var = $_SESSION['message'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `generator` WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `generator` ) && id !=".$var." ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
$generatorQuery = $con->query($query);
while($row = $generatorQuery->fetch_object()) {

$row->id = $_SESSION['message'];
echo $row->title;

}

?>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not updated your $_SESSION["message"];

Use this:

```
$_SESSION['message'] = $row->id;
```

instead of this:

```
$row->id = $_SESSION['message'];
```

- Avoid sql injection by escaping your variables in your query.